# Devo evitar subqueries?

Tags: banco-de-dados, query

#### Cenário exemplo

Tenho 3 tabelas: `relatorios`, `atividades` e `carros`.

Tabela `relatorios`, será a "capa" do dia, com data, quilometragem inicial e final, etc.

Tabela `atividades`, será cada atividade realizada no dia, ligada a um registro `relatorio`.

Tabela `carros`, com cadastros dos veículos disponíveis.

Vamos considerar, que existem 100 funcionários, com aproximadamente 10 atividades por dia, gerando 100 relatórios e 1000 atividades.

O carro será trocado a cada 6 meses entre os funcionários, então, ficarão 3 meses com o mesmo veículos.

---

#### Exemplo 1

Posso ter um campo `carroid` na minha tabela `relatórios`, assim quando for gerar uma consulta analítica, fazer um `join` e já sei o carro utilizado.

```
SELECT * FROM atividades a
LEFT JOIN carros c ON c.id = a.carroid
```

---

#### Exemplo 2

Como não muda muito, qual carro está sendo utilizado, poderia criar uma 4 tabela.

Tabela `carroperiodo`, onde tenho apenas a data do início da utilização (`datainicio`).

Assim, usaria subquery para consultar na data, qual era o carro utilizado:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT carroid FROM carros WHERE datainicio <= r.data LIMIT 1)
FROM atividades a
LEFT JOIN relatorios r ON r.id = a.relatorio
```

---

#### Dúvidas

- Quando vale eu ter repetidas vezes um `id` em uma tabela, para evitar uma subquery?
- O quanto subqueries afetam a performance de uma consulta?
- De que formas poderia melhorá-las? Ou nem usá-las!?

Comment: Em qual sistema de base de dados? E quais são os índices nessas tabelas? Otimização de queries é algo bastante específico para cada caso de uso, o ideal é sempre testar mais de uma solução. Não existe solução universal.

Comment: @bfavaretto O BD seria qualquer um relacional. Alterei um ponto importante na pergunta. "O carro será trocado a cada 6 meses entre os funcionários, então, ficarão 3 meses com o mesmo veículos". Quanto aos índices, se caso for uma opção de "solução", gostaria de ver um exemplo. (caso precise, podemos adotar um BD específico para a pergunta).